# Websphere Message broker multi-instance message flow

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker

I am looking for a command to change the message broker message flow instance in the run time. I know it is quite easy with MB explorer. But I am more interested towards the server side mqsi command. Ours is a AIX env with message broker 8 installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of instances a message flow has on the execution group is configured in the BAR file, before deployment.
If you want to change the number of additional instances you will need to redeploy your flow.

You can use the mqsiapplybaroverride command to change the configuration of the flow in the BAR file, and the mqsideploy command to redeploy the BAR.

Answer (score 2):

As of IIB v9 you can control the number of instances dynamically at runtime by assigning a workload management policy.

See the description here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bn34262_.htm

Once you have assigned a policy you can change it using the mqsichangepolicy command specifying an xml policy document that has a different number of instances.

Alternatively you can use the web ui to change it directly on the running broker.